# Getting Margin size on 1000 pdf files and loaded fonts

Tags: pdf, fonts, margin

I have over 1000 PDF files that I need to determine which ones have a margin size smaller than 1/4 inch.  I have looked at Ghostscript, and it looks promising, but I have not be able to figure out how to do more than 1 pdf at a time.

As a second requirement, I need to check if the PDF files have the fonts loaded in them.  I am stuck on this requirement and have no clue what I can do to automate this task.

I am fairly limited in my scripting knowledge and stick mostly to VBscript, some VB, and WSH

Answer (score 0):

Ghostscript has a device `-sDEVICE=bbox` which should help you.

The undocumented option `-csp3` in [cpdf](http://community.coherentpdf.com/) uses ghostscript in this way and extracts and prints the results, one for each page.

```
feast: john$ ./cpdf -gs /usr/local/bin/gs -csp3 ~/trunk/PDFTests/car.pdf
16.802291, 13.982754, 23.792892, 10.398033
16.882926, 14.002913, 8.798058, 13.134733
16.802291, 13.974525, 8.855073, 15.244272
16.802291, 13.962596, 8.862199, 13.391299
16.802291, 10.313868, 8.847946, 13.377045
16.802291, 13.962596, 8.855073, 17.040232
16.802291, 13.902119, 8.855073, 13.391299
```

For your second problem:

```
cpdf -missing-fonts file.pdf
```

will print any missing fonts out.

Comment: That is great info, thank you.  How would I go about doing these tasks for multiple PDFs in one shot, instead of doing individually?

Comment: You would need to control the `cpdf` command with a batch or shell script of some kind, or write a program yourself which calls it on each file. This is very specific to your environment...